# 'INSERT INTO' suddenly give back error 'PRIMARY KEY must be unique'

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

I've an sqlite database on my iOS app.
I found out I'd a mistake with the columns' numbers, then I changed to the correct one and since then I get an error 'PRIMARY KEY must be unique'.
Before the mistake all went well (beside 2 columns that misplaced values).

My code:

```
- (BOOL)createGroupMemberTable {
    char *error = NULL;
    const char *sqlStatment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '%@' (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %@ INTEGER, %@ INTEGER, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT, '%@' TEXT);", kTableNameGroupMember, kMemberID, kGroupID, kName, kTime, kLatitude, kLongitude, kMobile, kVisible, kAddress, kPicture].UTF8String;
    int responseCode = sqlite3_exec(_database, sqlStatment, NULL, NULL, &error);
    
    if (responseCode != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(_database);
        printf("Table 'GroupMember' failed to create, responseCode: %i\n", responseCode);
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)addGroupMember:(GroupMember*)aGroupMember {
    char *error = NULL;
    const char *sqlStatment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@ ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@') VALUES (%i, %i, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@');", kTableNameGroupMember, kMemberID, kGroupID, kName, kTime, kLatitude, kLongitude, kMobile, kVisible, kAddress, kPicture, aGroupMember.memberID, aGroupMember.groupID, aGroupMember.name, aGroupMember.time, aGroupMember.latitude, aGroupMember.longitude, aGroupMember.mobile, aGroupMember.visible, aGroupMember.address, aGroupMember.picture].UTF8String;
    int responseCode = sqlite3_exec(_database, sqlStatment, NULL, NULL, &error);
    
    if (responseCode != SQLITE_OK) {
        printf("\n\nFailed to insert into 'GroupMember' table, responseCode: %i\n", responseCode);
        printf("Error Message: %s\n\n", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

It might be irrelevant but this is my code to db creation:

```
static SQLiteHandler *_database;

+ (SQLiteHandler*)database {
    if (_database == nil) {
        _database = [[SQLiteHandler alloc] init];
    }
    return _database;
}

- (NSString*)databasePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"social.sqlite3"];
}

- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        const char *fileName = [self databasePath].UTF8String;
        
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", fileName]]) {
            printf("SQLITE EXISTS\n");
        }
        else {
             printf("SQLITE NOT EXISTS\n");
            const char *finalPath = [self databasePath].UTF8String;
            printf("File 'social.sqlite3' created at path: %s\n", finalPath);
        }
           
        
        printf("fileName: %s\n", fileName);
        int responseCode = sqlite3_open(fileName, &_database);
        
        if (responseCode != SQLITE_OK) {
            printf("Failed to open database, responseCode: %i\n", responseCode);
        }
        
        [self createGroupTable];
        [self createGroupMemberTable];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Error log:

> Failed to insert into 'GroupMember' table, responseCode: 19 Error
> Message: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
>
> ## define SQLITE_CONSTRAINT  19   /* Abort due to constraint violation */

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Answer was as I thought eventually as commented here by 'Petesh'.
All answers are correct so I'll mark the 1st one.

Comment: At a wild guess, you've got data with a group member ID already in the DB that you're trying to add with the updated code. How are you generating this member id? Have you got old member IDs that are now blocking the insert of new ID's because you're trying to recycle the numbers in the new insert? You should dump the content of the table, or the conflicting id when you get a key conflict which will help in this case

Comment: OK, thats crossed my mind and I replaced my code now and it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert/update a record with a primary key that already exists in your database. Have another look at the primary key of the record you are trying to change and see if there is a record in your database with the same primary key (unique identifier for a specific record).

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting a group member with the same primary key (member ID). You should try to check if this member ID is present in the database.

You could also decide to replace all values if the group member already exists, using INSERT OR REPLACE INTO:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO %@ ('%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@') VALUES (%i, %i, '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@', '%@');", kTableNameGroupMember, kMemberID, kGroupID, kName, kTime, kLatitude, kLongitude, kMobile, kVisible, kAddress, kPicture, aGroupMember.memberID, aGroupMember.groupID, aGroupMember.name, aGroupMember.time, aGroupMember.latitude, aGroupMember.longitude, aGroupMember.mobile, aGroupMember.visible, aGroupMember.address, aGroupMember.picture].UTF8String;
```

Answer (score 1):

Primary keys are the way the database identifies each row, thus you can not insert a record with the same primary key as has already been used.

It looks like what is happening is that when you restarted after the error, you didn't delete the app first so it used the database already created instead of restarting from scratch.  Then when you called addGroupMember it reused a value for kTableNameGroupMember which I think is your primary key.